# Case vba is skipping over the correct case

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim score As Variant
score = Range("KPI!A6").Value

Select Case score
  Case score = "January"
    Columns("D:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "February"
    Columns("C:C,E:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "March"
    Columns("C:D,F:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "April"
    Columns("C:E,G:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "May"
    Columns("C:F,H:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "June"
    Columns("C:G,I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "July"
    Columns("C:H,J:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "August"
    Columns("C:I,K:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "September"
    Columns("C:J,L:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "October"
    Columns("C:K,M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "November"
    Columns("C:L,N:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "December"
    Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Select

End Sub
```

Hey all!  This is my first question, so hopefully I'm not doing things incorrectly.  In any case (pun intended here).... I have some relatively basic "case" code that should be looking at the cell value of A6 and hiding columns based on which month is showing.  I'm having a hard time figuring out why it's skipping over the correct case (in this instance "May").  I can step through the code, but it is not stopping to perform the hide columns part.  It just keeps going, checking each case and eventually hits the end of the sub and ends.  I don't receive any errors, it just doesn't catch the correct value and perform the action.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is in `KPI!A6`? is it a date formatted `MMMM`? or is it the word `May` as text?  In other words, when you click on the cell, what is displayed in the formula bar?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses so far everyone!  I did go back and modify my code to change the "Case = "January"" and just make it "Case "January"".  I did this because the month is in text format, not "MMM" format like Scott asked.  The code does run now and selects the correct case, but now I am receiving a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error.  I've looked all over for a solution, but can't seem to find what is causing this error or how to fix.  Any ideas?  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: You need to ask a new question with the updated code.  Select YowE3K as the correct answer by clicking the check mark by the answer.   The create a new post.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I've marked YowE3K as the correct answer and I'll continue to search for the answer, but create a new post if I still can't find anything.  Appreciate all the help on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `score` is a string such as `January` then `score = "January"` (etc) will return `True` (or `False`).  `True` (or `False`) won't be equal to the value of `score` (i.e. `"January"`), so therefore none of your tests will be satisfied.

You probably meant to say:

```
Dim score As Variant
score = Range("KPI!A6").Value

Select Case score
Case "January"
    Columns("D:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "February"
    Columns("C:C,E:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "March"
    Columns("C:D,F:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "April"
    Columns("C:E,G:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "May"
    Columns("C:F,H:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "June"
    Columns("C:G,I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "July"
    Columns("C:H,J:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "August"
    Columns("C:I,K:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "September"
    Columns("C:J,L:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "October"
    Columns("C:K,M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "November"
    Columns("C:L,N:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "December"
    Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Select

End Sub
```

which will compare the value of `score` to each of the literal strings `"January"`, `"February"`, etc, in turn and execute the first `Case` where the comparison is `True`.

---

Or, as Jeeped suggests, to avoid removing `score =` from each of your `Case` statements you could use:

```
Dim score As Variant
score = Range("KPI!A6").Value

Select Case True
  Case score = "January"
    Columns("D:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "February"
    Columns("C:C,E:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "March"
    Columns("C:D,F:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "April"
    Columns("C:E,G:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "May"
    Columns("C:F,H:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "June"
    Columns("C:G,I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "July"
    Columns("C:H,J:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "August"
    Columns("C:I,K:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "September"
    Columns("C:J,L:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "October"
    Columns("C:K,M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "November"
    Columns("C:L,N:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case score = "December"
    Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Select

End Sub
```

which will compare the value `True` to each of the logical expressions such as `score = January`, `score = February`, etc, in turn and execute the first `Case` where the comparison to `True` returns `True`.

---

The `Select Case` statement is just a prettied-up `If` statement.  The following `Select Case` statement

```
Select Case x
    Case y
        DoSomething
    Case z
        DoSomethingElse
End Select
```

is equivalent to the following `If` statement

```
If x = y Then
    DoSomething
ElseIf x = z Then
    DoSomethingElse
End If
```

Comment: ... or to avoid retyping all of the original just change to `Select Case True`.

Comment: @Jeeped I try to avoid `Select Case True` when I can, even if it **does** mean retyping the OP's code. :D

Comment: ... welll, yeah ... it can be a little non-intuitive but sometimes it **has** to be used.

Comment: @Jeeped Yeah, and I reluctantly use it in those cases - but if someone at my work showed me code using `Select Case True` and then every `Case` started with `Case score = ..` I would scream and rant and rave at them, so I had better not be hypocritical and use it here just to save myself from deleting `score =` 12 times.  :D

Comment: Agreed. It is possible that the OP frankenstein'ed together a couple of sample code snippets but the correct method should be shown. I included my comment as a pointer to what was actually wrong with the original.

Answer (score 4):

No need to do the Select Case:

```
Dim score As Variant
With Worksheets("KPI")
    score = .Range("A6").Value
    'if score is a date remove this next line
    score = DateValue(1 & " " & score & " 2017")
    .Columns("C:N").Hidden = True
    .Columns(Month(score) + 2).Hidden = False
End With
```

Comment: Showoff!! :D :D